# Is it correct? $n^{(\log\,x)} = x^ {(\log\,n)} $?

Tags: logarithms

Is it correct?
$$n^{(\log\,x)} = x^ {(\log\,n)} $$
Can you proof and describe that, for any base?
Please explain completely.
Thank you.

Comment: Are their logarithms the same?

Comment: The n and x are not same.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/794187/number-raised-to-log-expression

Answer (score 7):

Hint: compute the logarithm of both sides. Since the logarithm function is one-to-one this will tell you if they are equal.

Answer (score 7):

$
n^{(\log x)} = (e^{\log n})^{(\log x)} = e^{(\log n)(\log x)} = e^{(\log x)(\log n)}= (e^{\log x})^{(\log n)} =  x^{(\log n)}
$

If you use $\log$ to a different base $b$, then use $b$ instead of $e$.